# Virtualhost adding another domain to server

Tags: debian, domain, virtualhost, bind, apache-2.2

I'm trying to add another domain to my server.
I followed this : http://www.Debian-administration.org/articles/412

Basically, I created a new file called

> www.site.com

in the

> /etc/apache/sites-available/

What's the next step? I created a file in

> /var/lib/named/etc/bind/zones/master

As well, site.com.db and included it in my "named.conf.local"

Restart Apache and Bind, but it does not work. when i nslookup site.com I get this error:

> ;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 8.8.8.8,
>   trying next server Server:
>   8.8.8.8 Address:        8.8.8.8#53

If I change my hosts(Not the server (C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts)) and point the domain to my server IP, the server will work for me.

Anyone got any idea or want more information?
 << The CNAME and all that is missing.

> ** server can't find site.com: NXDOMAIN
>
> ; <<>> DiG 9.6-ESV-R4 <<>> @localhost www.site.com
>   ; (3 servers found)
>   ;; global options: +cmd
>   ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
>
> ; <<>> DiG 9.6-ESV-R4 <<>>
>   @93.190.139.208 www.site.com ; (1
>   server found) ;; global options: +cmd
>   ;; connection timed out; no servers
>   could be reached

```
 netstat -nulp | grep :53
udp        0      0 93.190.139.210:53       0.0.0.0:*                           7057/named
udp        0      0 93.190.139.209:53       0.0.0.0:*                           7057/named
udp        0      0 93.190.139.208:53       0.0.0.0:*                           7057/named
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           7057/named
udp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                                7057/named
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SERVFAIL response probably means problems in your DNS configuration, but to be sure try this instead:

`dig @yourserver www.site.com`

If it still returns a SERVFAIL you can be sure your config went wrong somewhere. In that case post the relevant block of your named.conf.local and the zone file for that domain. Also take a look at /var/log/daemon.log immediatly after restarting BIND - it should provide hints at what is wrong.

Comment: @Eduardo I. Ops, Added the code in first post. Any idea?

Thanks for replying.

Comment: I see dig is not able to reach the DNS server. What IP is it listening on? You can check this using `netstat -nulp | grep :53`.

Comment: @Eduardo I. Added in first post, those three IPs?

Comment: I see. Well, you seem not to be reaching BIND, even though you should. Do you have any iptables rules up? `iptables -nvL INPUT | grep 53`. If you restart BIND do you see anything related to this zone in the log files?

Comment: It somehow started to work. Maybe I had to wait? I waited like two hours. Its good to know what I did wrong. I didn't edit anything and suddenly it started to work. Well, Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it, I really do. Thanks again!

Comment: That's strange... external DNS servers shouldn't cache SERVFAIL for more than 5 mins according to the RFC, so that can't be it. Well, I'm glad it's fixed anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Got it all wrong in the first place...

the question led me into a wrong direction. Basically you have to make your PC ask the server for the route to the domain. This can be done by adding the domain to the hosts filo of each client that should resolve the domain or use a DNS. This can also be a router where you can add so called hosts. 
You can also publish an alternate nameserver in your Network via router or set a custom route in every client.

Comment: With this method, my visitors needs to change their host file? Sorry if I misunderstood. Thanks for replying.